# Use command button to open selected record on a form without filtering?

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, button, filtering

I have a continuous form which displays a small amount of data from each record in my table ProjectT (i.e. project name, status) and a command button in the footer which I would like to open the selected record in its expanded single form (where all of the relevant info is displayed).

At first I set this button up using Access's wizard, but realized that Access opens a selected record by filtering the data on the form.  The problem with this is that once the expanded form is opened, I want a user to be able to move to other records without having to select to unfilter the results.  If I change the button on my continuous form to simply open the expanded single form, is there code I can run to make the form open to the selected record without putting a filter on?

Initially I thought to set the expanded form's (named ProjectF) default value to `Forms!ProjectListF!ProjectID` (where ProjectListF is the continuous form and ProjectID is the autonumber primary key for ProjectT), but this was not successful, I think because there is more than one ProjectID displayed on ProjectListF.

Another thing to consider is that I have another button on my Main Menu form which opens the ProjectF form in data entry mode to prevent the user inadvertently changing/deleting an existing record when they are trying to add a new one; I have no idea if this might be important when trying to find a solution to my issue.

I'm open to any suggestion--I have an okay handle on SQL, and have delved into a little VBA but am completely self taught. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the detailed form with this command:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "ProjectF", , , "[ProjectID] = " & Me!ProjectID.Value & ""
```